# Binding dictionary to combobox

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-8, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml

I am trying to bind a dictionary to combobox but on UI there is no Item displayed only blank items are Binded. Please find the code below and let me know what I am doing wrong?

Code:

```
private Dictionary<string, string> _timeToExpirationValues = 
new Dictionary<string, string>     { "< 15 Days", "15" },
                                   { "< 30 Days", "30" },
                                   { "< 60 Days", "60" },
                                   { "< 90 Days", "90" },
                                   { "< 1 year", "365" }};


        /// <summary>
        /// Gets or sets the filter settings data.
        /// </summary>
        /// <value>
        /// The filter settings data.
        /// </value>
        public Dictionary<string, string> TimeToExpirationValues
        {
            get { return _timeToExpirationValues; }
            set { SetProperty(ref _timeToExpirationValues, value); }
        }
```

XAML Code:

```
 <ComboBox Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" 
                                  ItemsSource="{Binding TimeToExpirationValues}"
                                  DisplayMemberPath="Key"
                                  SelectedValuePath="Value" />
```

What is been displayed is as below:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be known bug. Here's some links for you. I tried [this Silverlight sample](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/mgold/binding-to-a-combobox-to-a-dictionary-in-silverlight-using-mvvm/) for Windows Store App, I am also getting white items only w/o text.

[Binding a Dictionary to a WinRT ListBox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13330938/binding-a-dictionary-to-a-winrt-listbox)

[TargetException error in Binding - MSDN Forum](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winappswithcsharp/thread/234a17ad-975f-42f6-aa91-7212deda4190)

[TargetException error in Binding to Dictionary<string, object> - Submitted Bug](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/750518/targetexception-error-in-binding-to-dictionary-string-object)

Answer (score 1):

Have you set DataContext to the window or ComboBox? if it's not you should add these lines to your window

```
<Window.DataContext>
        <local:YourClassName/>
    </Window.DataContext>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this (note the extra word `Path`):

```
<ComboBox Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" 
                              ItemsSource="{Binding Path=TimeToExpirationValues}"
                              DisplayMemberPath="Key"
                              SelectedValuePath="Value" />
```

Comment: Actually I can see that those many Items are been binded but not displayed on the UI?

Answer (score 0):

I tried your example and it was working here.

So i think, that you have just a white foreground for the labels inside the combox. (Maybe declared as styles in the app.xaml?).