# ListView Binding With ObservableCollection of KeyValuePair

Tags: listview, windows-8, windows-runtime, microsoft-metro, winrt-xaml

Hello friends i am getting a problem of displaying text in TextBlock which is defined in ListView Datatemplate here is the code of my listview.

```
<ListView Grid.Row="1" Margin="-2,0,0,-5" Padding="0" ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource  listviewItemSampleStyleWithNoselection}" ItemsSource="{Binding lst}" SelectionMode="None" >
                    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <Button FontSize="15" BorderThickness="0" Background="#8A69A7"  >
                                <Button.ContentTemplate>
                                    <DataTemplate>
                                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" VerticalAlignment="Top" Background="#8A69A7" >
                                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Value}" FontSize="15" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
                                            <TextBlock x:Name="btnremoveSubject" Margin="10,0,-5,0" VerticalAlignment="Center" Padding="0" FontSize="15" Text="&#xE10A;" FontFamily="Segoe UI Symbol" Width="20" Height="18" HorizontalAlignment="Center"  Foreground="White" FontWeight="Thin" />
                                        </StackPanel>
                                    </DataTemplate>
                                </Button.ContentTemplate>
                            </Button>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    <ListView.ItemsPanel>
                        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                            <VirtualizingStackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" />
                        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    </ListView.ItemsPanel>
                </ListView>
```

here lst is my ObservableCollection of type KeyValuePair here its defination..

```
  public ObservableCollection<KeyValuePair<string,string>> lst { get; set; }
```

all item in lst is already populated with key and values. so will you guys please guide me what i have do any kind of help and suggestion is appreciated.

Comment: try to remove StackPanel and check it.

Comment: not working..but it does not make any difference is stackpanel is thr or not..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WinRT is having bug. You can't bind `Dictionary<T,V>`, `ObservableCollection<KeyValuePair<T, V>>` or `IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<T, V>>`. You have only one choice is to use the properties as member of class.

You can also test using simple converter to check if binding is happening or not.

[Binding a Dictionary to a WinRT ListBox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13330938/binding-a-dictionary-to-a-winrt-listbox)

[Submitted bug](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/750518/targetexception-error-in-binding-to-dictionary-string-object)