# How to directly bind to a Dictionary in Windows Phone 8.1

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8.1, windows-8.1

I have `Dictionary<string,string>` which I need to bind directly to a `ListView` in Windows Phone 8.1. The `ListView` is defined as follows:

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Companies}">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Key}" />
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Value}" />
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
```

And my Dictionary has being initialized with some random values.

```
Companies = new Dictionary<string, string>
            {
                {"abc","hello" },
                {"def","listen" },
                {"ghi","please" },
                {"jkl","help" }
            };
```

I get the following error.

> Error: Cannot get 'Value' value (type 'String') from type
>   'System.Runtime.InteropServices.WindowsRuntime.CLRIKeyValuePairImpl`2[[System.String,
>   mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e],[System.String, mscorlib,
>   Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e]],
>   mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e'. BindingExpression: Path='Value'
>   DataItem='System.Runtime.InteropServices.WindowsRuntime.CLRIKeyValuePairImpl`2[[System.String,
>   mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e],[System.String, mscorlib,
>   Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e]],
>   mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e'; target element is
>   'Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.TextBlock' (Name='null'); target property is
>   'Text' (type 'String').

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13330938/binding-a-dictionary-to-a-winrt-listbox

Comment: Maybe interesting https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/234a17ad-975f-42f6-aa91-7212deda4190/targetexception-error-in-binding?forum=winappswithcsharp

Comment: Don't bind to dictionaries, they suck at binding.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using Dictionary'<'string,string'>', try to encapsulate your logic  into a class and use an ObservableCollection'<'YourType'>'. For example let's suppose you have

```
public class Car
{
   public string Make{get;set;}
   public string Model{get;set;}
}
```

And then, in your xaml you would have:

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Companies}">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Make}" />
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Model}" />
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```