# Is it possible to place/bind dictionary in a datagridview and make it editiable?

Tags: c#, winforms, dictionary, datagridview

I have a nested dictionary containing limits as follows:
Dictionary<double, Dictionary<double, double>>. The format of the data is: Dictionary<Frequency, Dictionary<Min, Max>>.

I want to bind this dictionary to a datagridview. The first key will never have more than one Value (dictionary) and likewise applies to the sub-dictionary.

I have three columns inside my datagridview and I want to bind the dictionary to it. The three columns are Frequency, Min, max. I want each key in the main dictionary to be a new row and min and max for that frequency will be from the keys value. Is this possible?

Secondly, when this is achieved. I want the user to be able to insert new rows, with a new frequency value and a new min max value. As it is bound to the dictionary the dictionary will also have this new entry/row.

I've only been coding for 2-3 months and before I go down a rabbit hole. Is this possible with winforms?

Comment: use converter:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35158821/bind-to-arbitrary-dictionary-by-using-a-converter-to-cast-object

Answer (score 0):

I don't see why you need dictionaries for that.
You can model your data structure as a single class, than you can nicely bind it to the datagridview.

```
public class Frequency
{
    public double Value { get; set; }
    public double Min { get; set; }
    public double Max { get; set; }
}
```

Then in the form constructor for example:

```
private BindingList<Frequency> _frequencies;

public MyForm()
{
    var frequency1 = new Frequency { Value = 1, Min = 0, Max = 3 };
    var frequency2 = new Frequency { Value = 1, Min = 0, Max = 3 };
    var frequency3 = new Frequency { Value = 1, Min = 0, Max = 3 };

    _frequencies = new BindingList<Frequency>
    {
       .AllowNew = true,
       .AllowEdit = true,
       .AllowRemove = false,
    };

    _frequencies.Add(frequency1);
    _frequencies.Add(frequency2);
    _frequencies.Add(frequency3);

    myDataGridView.DataSource = frequencies;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this. I went for this method. However due to how I am getting this data I hacve everything in a nested dictionary. I then created a list of classes List<Frequencies> from the dictionary and I passed that list to datagridview.

My issue is now, I cannot add new rows to the datagridview. It seems to be that I cannot add rows when the control is data-bound. I created a button "add row" and used 
 dataGridView1.Rows.Add();